# Slim calling endpoint in browser

Tags: php, url-routing, slim

I am new in Slim, I want to create a small website, I used Slim to create an API an all is fine but when I came to displaying endpoint in browser I stack.
with a restful tester or curl , it works fine, but when I browse : path_to_index/hello ,I get 404 error.
with path_to_index/index.php/hello it works. how can I change it to make path_to_index/hello works

Here is my index :

```
require 'vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();   
$app->get('/hello', function () {
    echo "Hello";
});
$app->run();
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Be sure to place your `htaccess` next to your `index.php` - with this setup.
2. When using `composer` you also could `require` vendor autoloader:

```or-tag-here
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: I needed also to edit AllowOverride All then run sudo a2enmod rewrite to avoid Internal 500 error the restart Apache2